# How to know the index of a selected cell in Angular 6 material MatTable?

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I'm creating web application using Angular 6 about an online quiz which contain some questions that its option look like a table. I've used MatTableSourcedata to display the content of rows and columns, I've some columns that are a check boxes to be checked for choosing.
Here's column def code :

```
<!-- Checkbox Column --> 
<ng-container matColumnDef="select5">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Always </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row ;let i = index;">
<div *ngFor="let number of question.options">
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="option.number" (change)="onSelect(question, 
option);">
</mat-checkbox>
</div>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

And this is the onSelect method :

```
onSelect(question: Question, option: Option) {
if (question.questionTypeId === 3) {
this.config.requiredAll = true;
question.options.forEach((x) => { if (x.id !== option.id) x.selected = 
false; });
this.option.number = this.selection.selected.length;
}
else {
this.config.requiredAll = false;
}
console.log(question.options);
}
```

If you need more code or more explaination let me know please, I've to know how to assign the selected cell index to the option number.

Comment: You can add index value to onSelect(question, option, i) method

Comment: Can you give me more details please?

Comment: After you added '<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="option.number" (change)="onSelect(question, 
option,i);">', you can use in 'onSelect(question: Question, option: Option, index: number)' function